# How to combine two SQL queries with dynamic table name into one in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL function which I'm trying to figure out how to make into one query:

```
async function verifyInteractiveInstanceAttributeIsUnique(typeId, key, val, attrSchema) {
  const tableName = getTableName(attrSchema.type)
  const instances = await knex.from(`links`)
    .select('id')
    .where('parent_id', typeId)
    .where('name', 'instance')
  const instanceIds = instances.map(x => x.id)
  const existingRecord = await knex.from(tableName)
    .whereIn('parent_id', instanceIds)
    .where('name', key)
    .first()
  return !existingRecord
}
```

Essentially I think this is the SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM links
WHERE parent_id = ${typeId}
AND name = 'instance'
# store in IDS array lets say

SELECT * FROM ${tableName}
WHERE parent_id IN (IDS)
AND name = ${key}
LIMIT 1
```

How can I write this in plain SQL to do the query in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample SQL, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ${tableName} t
WHERE t.parent_id IN (SELECT l.id
                      FROM links l
                      WHERE l.parent_id = ${typeId} AND
                            lname = 'instance' 
                     ) AND
      t.l.name = ${key}
LIMIT 1
```